# How can we split js file from phtml file

Tags: magento2, javascript, phtml

We currently have a large phtml file that is essentially a plain JavaScript file, eg.,

```
<?php
  // some conditional check. about 10 lines of code
>

<script>
// here is 1000 lines of JavaScript
</script>
```

We want so split JavaScript into separate file so editor can have syntax highlight and we can run linters on JS file. What is the best way to split JS file into separate file but at run time still inline JavaScript code (so client doesn't have to fetch separate JS file)?

Comment: Write all script codes in new js file. And call that js file from layout XML.

Comment: I'm noob to magento. how can I call js? Do I just echo?

Comment: Have you created any file in `view/frontend/layout/`?

Comment: yes currently I'm loading phtml from layout XML. I now understand you're suggesting I can directly load js file - that makes more sense. Is there a way for me to still control whether I inject js or not based on some php?

Comment: Please add this in XML: `<head>
        <script src="Vendor_Module::js/newfile.js"/>
    </head>` and move all script code to this js file.

Comment: 404 not found. where should I put js file? also can I control (based on php logic) visibility of this JS file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100731/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-kazuki).

Answer (score 1):

Please add this code in layout XML `view/frontend/layout/`

```
<head>
    <script src="Vendor_Module::js/newfile.js"/>
</head>
```

Or else add below script in php,

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $repo = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository');
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $repo->getUrl("MyModule::js/my.js") ?>"></script>
```

And move all script code to this js file. And then check it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to place script at `before.body.end` and I had some php logic so I wanted to keep phtml. I end up having phtml like

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$repo = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository');

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $repo->getUrl("MyModule::js/my.js") ?>"></script>
```

and I put my.js file in `view/frontend/web/js`